# How do I get two different displacements to follow a texture mask

Tags: texture-painting, displacement

Hi I'm pretty new to this. I made one textures and downloaded another off of Polygon and I figured out how to use a texture mask to paint what part of my object has one texture and what part has the other (grass and dirt). However I can't get the same to work with displacement. The grass has very specific displacement pattern and I don't want that showing up where the dirt is supposed to be. I can't figure out how to get the displacement to follow the texture mask as well. I tried plugging the two displacements through a MixRGB and then into a displacement but the dirt still had the grass texture in material preview and in render it looked like the photo I linked so no luck there.[image]

Comment: if you are posting a picture of your node tree next time, please make sure that we can read it. Thank you. It might be helpful if you just paste more image so you don't run into the "picture too big" problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try out this setup here:

[image]

[image]